# Makefile help. Adapting a makefile to work on my machine

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

I have a makefile which works on the University machines using some code written by the university, as well as the GSL library. I've installed GSL on my computer and run a couple test programs, confirming the library works.

My Program consists of my own file, Ex1.cc and the files constants.hh and constants.cc (object files for these found in cavlib.a), where the number pi is defined (in a namespace, C). I want to get my program compile on my own computer, and so am trying to adapt the makefile accordingly, however I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "C::pi", referenced from:
      _main in Ex1-e24691.o
      Generate_Rand_Set(gsl_rng*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in Ex1-e24691.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The makefile used reads:

```
LIBCONFIG_DIR=/usr/local/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I$(LIBCONFIG_DIR)
LDFLAGS=
LDLIBS=$(HOME)/Documents/C++/Part\ II/Exercise\ 1/cavlib/cavlib.a -lgsl -lgslcblas -lstdc++ 
CXX=g++ -g -pedantic -Wall 
# Pick up modifications for compiling on mac (if present)
-include ../mac.mk

%.exe : %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS)  $< $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is ios, not OS X?

Comment: What is `Ex1-e24691.o`? Is it in `cavlib.a`? Your makefile doesn't build `.o` files at all; it builds `.exe` files from `.cc` files directly. Do you need to build `cavlib.a` for your system instead of using someone else's which was compiled for a different machine/architecture?

Comment: I think Etan is right.  Where di you get cavlib.a ?  You can't just copy a compiled library to a different OS and have it work.  You may need to build the library for your OS.

Comment: Thanks guys! Made cavlib.a again myself and all worked. I thought object files were specific to compiler, and so all would be fine as both machines used g++, guess I was wrong!